# How to reuse instantiated component in a Angular Material dialog?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-lifecycle-hooks

We are trying to create a component that has two "view states" - state A is just as usual in the document flow (kinf of like a preview/thumbnail). State b should be a enlarged version of it (modal).

We had no problem to create a component and use it in a page (state A). Then we implemented a function to enlarge it ([Angular Mat dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)) which is state B.
Unfortunately this will create a new instance of our component and we will lose all instantiated data/state.

Question: Is it possible to reuse the component instance to keep state and potentially save resources?

Comment: Usually reusing component instance is strange idea...

Comment: @Petr Averyanov that doesn‘t really help lol. It‘s more like taking it with everything it‘s got and displaying it somewhere different.